# Rasing events and handling them

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to get this event to fire on my main from but at present it is not firing and updating the progress bar in my class it is called as following

```
   Private Sub _onTransferStart(ByVal source As String, ByVal destination As String,   ByVal transferredBytes As Integer, ByVal totalBytes As Integer, ByVal message As String) Handles transfer.OnTransferStart
    RaiseEvent onTransferStart(source, destination, transferredBytes, totalBytes, message)
End Sub
```

then I handled it in my form as follows but its not updating my progress bar for some reas but yet when i set brake point on the ontransferstart it does indead show bytes are downloaded

[image]

This is how im calling my on trafnerstart

```
 Private Sub onTransferStart(ByVal source As String, ByVal destination As String, ByVal transferredBytes As Integer, ByVal totalBytes As Integer, ByVal message As String) Handles transfer.onTransferStart
    Me.ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = totalBytes
    Me.tbStatus.Text = "Transfer started.."
End Sub
```

I should have stated that I am calling it via a background worker already

```
  Private Sub bgroundDownload_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As  
  System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgroundDownload.DoWork

  Dim wcEDIimport As New wcEDIimport
 e.Result = wcEDIimport.DownloadPricat()
 End Sub

 Private Sub bgroundDownload_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As   
System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles  
bgroundDownload.RunWorkerCompleted
Dim results As Boolean = CBool(e.Result)
If results = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("The download is completed: " & results.ToString)
End If
end sub
```

Comment: @Steven Dogget made the change their

Comment: Please create a separate project and try to reproduce the issue there. Post back with results. Debugging through your code is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This gives an example of raising and consuming events. I think your issue is, the class raising the event should be different from where the addhandler is used.
You should not use raiseevent and addhandler in the same class.

Sample code:

```
Class A
    sub raiser()
        RaiseEvent anevent
    end sub
end class
Class B
     dim A1 as A
     sub New()
         AddHandler A1.anevent, AddressOf catchEvent
     End sub
     sub catachEvent()
          'do something here
     end sub
end class
```